# How to plot a colormap?

Tags: matlab, colors, color-mapping, colorbar

I have a map of Europe in Matlab, and I have some values, which change region by region.

How can I plot a contour colormap? The label colours depend on these values, and I want to show the colourbar, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = peaks(40); # some random data
contourf(a); # plot filled contour map
colormap(mycolors); # mycolors should be an N by 3 matrix specifying your colors
colorbar; # shows the color bar on the side
```

Comment: I couldnt implement this code to my programme. To be more specific,i will tell in detail. I really need help. i have a europe map, i plotted it with worldmap comment. Also i have some frequency values. this frequency values changes from region to region. So i want to show these frequency values with colours on the map. The frequency values is from 0 to 10.and i have 4 frequency values from spain,england,greece,czhech repuclic.Also I have lattitude and longitude values of these countries. And probably i should do something like fitting, to show the frequency values around these countries.